# Is it a good practice to use input parameters inside a method

Tags: c#

I need to know if it is a good practice to use same input parameters inside a method without assigning them to the method local variable. Following code blocks may describe the query more clear way.

Option 1: Input parameters use inside the method

```
public int SumValues(List<int> pLValues)
        {
            int _sum = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < pLValues.Count; i++)
            {
                _sum = +pLValues[i];
            }

            return _sum;
        }
```

Option 2: Assign to a local variable and use that inside the method.

```
public int SumValues(List<int> pLValues)
{
    int _sum = 0;
    List<int> _lVal = pLValues;

    for (int i = 0; i < _lVal.Count; i++)
    {
        _sum = +_lVal[i];
    }

    return _sum;
}
```

Please tell me what is the best way and why?

Comment: You should consider looking into C# naming conventions.

Comment: Also your function doesn't work. `SumValues(new List<int>(){1,1})` returns `1` instead of `2`  It should be `_sum += _lVal[i];`

Answer (score 7):

There's no benefit to declaring another local variable, so don't do it. (Think of a parameter as just being a local variable which is definitely assigned to start with.)

If you have a `ref` parameter and you don't want to change the value, *then* it would make sense to copy it into a new local variable, admittedly. Likewise if you need the original value later on, of course.

There are various changes I *would* make to your code, however:

- I'd use LINQ's `Sum` method to start with, of course :)
- I would ditch the prefixes you've got for your variables
- I'd probably change the input type to `IEnumerable<int>`
- I'd use a `foreach` loop instead of fetching by index

Comment: As long as it isn't reassigned later on in the method.  Keep the variable for the new instance.

Comment: @JeffMercado: I'm not sure what you mean, to be honest.

Comment: I'm looking at a lot of legacy code and they do this a lot. Variables are reused a lot (many times for completely different uses) and it's driving me nuts. :) A variable should be declared for every different use of the thing is what I'm saying.

Comment: @JeffMercado: Yes, that's fair enough - but surely that would extend to the parameter itself, wouldn't it? If you're taking one parameter but using it for two different purposes, that sounds like a problem to start with.

Comment: Thanks JonSkeet I just wanted to produce and example for the query so do not bother about the code. @JeffMercado when we declare different variable for each use doesn't the code end with lot of memory allocations without any use ?

Comment: @user1249197: I bother about the code because it's likely to be *indicative* of code you might otherwise write. If you're worried about how much memory your local variables are taking up, you're probably micro-optimizing... and you should probably break up your methods into smaller ones, too.

Comment: Thank very much @JonSkeet. I will work on my naming conventions :)

Answer (score 3):

it's exactly the same in your case `_lVal`is the same object as `pLValues`.

C# uses reference semantics. That is when you do

```
_lVal = pLValues;
```

you are stating that `_lVal` is a reference to the same object as `pLValues` and any changes you make to object referenced by `_lVal` will be observable through `pLValues`.

that is

```
_lVal.Add(int.MaxValue);
if(pLValues.Last() == int.MaxValue){
   //this will be true because the element added in the first line
   //is added to the object that both _lVal and pLValues references
}
```

In the case where the type of the parameter is a ValueType (such as int) it doesn't matter either but for other reasons. Since any assignment will be a copy assignment and the argument is there for a copy of what was passed to the method invocation. The scope of the copy is the same as the method (in the general case there are odd cases e.g. closing over the argument).

So in the end the short answer is. That you might as well not create a local variable since you gain nothing but loose readbility since it now not obvious when the parameter is used

Comment: I wouldn't talk about aliases like that - the two variables are *not* aliases, they just have the same values. Making a change to `_lVal` itself *won't* be visible in `pLValues`, whereas if you make a change to the data *within the object that the value of `_lVal` refers to*, that change will be visible however you access the object.

Comment: Yeah @JonSkeet youe're right they are two different references. I'll update

Comment: what if we pass a reference data type list apart from the primitive list ?

Comment: @user1249197 makes no difference to the argument